# Hides Bottom Bar On Push doesn't work

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have UINavigationController, that contains TabBarController.
Tab Bar child controllers always hide bottom tab bar, no matter "Hides Bottom Bar On Push" selected or not.

Tried to set programmatically:

```
downloadViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:downloadViewController animated:NO];
```

but still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing navigation controller,
and adding navigation controller for each tab.